How to change gnome-shell window style after regolith install modified it?
I tried installing Regolith to test it out, but I decided to stick with Gnome. Even after uninstalling Regolith, the window title bars in Gnome are modified, and now appear black with a red ex in a circle for the close button.
Choosing a different theme via the User Themes gnome shell extension changes the appearance of the top panel bar (with date, and battery info) but does not change the window title bar.
I haven't figured out how to modify the window title bar, back to what it was before, or to something new.
I'm running GNOME Shell 43.9, with Wayland, on Debian 12.
Thanks for any ideas!

screenshot of shell with window title bar with red ex
I can also see in gnome-tweaks that the shell theme is default. But when I modify this, it also does not change the window title bar styling -- so maybe something else is overriding it? note that the "x" button for the gnome-tweaks window appears different, but all other windows have the red "x" button at the top right.


Aw I figured it out, thanks for rubber-ducking! Just needed to change the theme color "Legacy Applications". Missed that setting before somehow.
